# Ubuntu apache process consuming 100% cpu PHP/MySQL app

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php

I have a server at Rackspace connecting to a Cloud DB instance running MySQL. I'm not a server admin so I apologize for not having enough data. I'm having a hard time determining what is causing my apache server to run up to 100% cpu with a load of 10 concurrent users (which I setup a load test using Neustar).

My `mod_status` output:

[image]

My `mpm_prefork.conf`:

```
 <IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers            2
    MinSpareServers         2
    MaxSpareServers         10
    MaxRequestWorkers       150
    MaxClients              10
    MaxConnectionsPerChild  0
 </IfModule>
```

I can appreciate that my problem is with the code, but I'm not clear on where to start or if there's details in the `mod_status` that I don't understand. We are using PDO to connect to the database and Rackspace makes us use DNS so I'm not sure if doing the reverse lookup is hurting the CPU. I also have 2 screen shots from New Relic showing the usage on the server. It's a small staging server which is why I have only 1CPU and 1G ram - and why I only tested with 10 users.

[image]

Please let me know what else I can post to help diagnose the issues.

Answer (score 0):

A proper answer to this question would take tens of thousands of words (I know, I've [tried to answer it before](http://lampe2e.blogspot.co.uk/)). But looking at the numbers you've provided does give some clues.

That you are using lots of CPU means you can eliminate a lot of potential problems. High CPU usage on a LAMP platform is usually quite a good sign - it implies that the system is **not** spending lots of time waiting for network, database and disk I/O to happen.

Having said that, a load average over 3 with only 10 concurrent connections is very poor. A response rate of 2.7 /sec is very poor. And I suspect the average response time is very, very poor.

It's so bad, the first thing I would do is check if there is any opcode cache configured at all. If there is, then you should check it is sized correctly.

> only 1CPU and 1G ram

I've run LAMP servers with 120 concurrent clients/instance with this amount of memory (and plenty left over for VFS and DB). Of course a lot depends on what your code looks like - and that is certainly not something which other people can give an informed opinion about here. Once you've checked out the opcode cache thing, you might want to install [XHPROF](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xhprof.php) and start investigating what's wrong with your code.

(BTW you seem to have a mix of 2.2 and 2.4 config directives in your httpd conf - you might want to spend some time cleaning that up too).

Comment: I've been doing a bunch of load testing and I really think it's my code. Are there any alternatives to XHPROF that I can use to dig through my code? I've transitioned to classes from procedural and it the problem must be in my classes somewhere. However, 3 days in and I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: load testing is not the right to check if your opcode cache is setup properly :). And if you've managed to rewrite your entire codebase in three days, this doesn't lend a lot of weight to to your theory. XHProf is the quickest route to your goal if the code is the problem.

Comment: I had meant our application rebuilt rebuilt using classes instead of the old version which was procedural. I'll take another look at XHPROF.

Comment: To narrow down, you could try limiting your load test. If you find out that the CPU spike only happens when you call page X, you should look at what that code does differently from the rest of your code and the answer will probably lie close.